# IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio terminal doesn't recognize emoji, while Mac terminal does

Tags: bash, macos, shell, intellij-idea, terminal

I have a different emoji in my .bash_profile config depending on the user in the terminal. I have both IntelliJ and Android Studio and the emoji shows as a broken character (Two squares). Is there any way to get intellij to recognize emoji. I have a couple of user profiles and I set the emoji to provide me with an easy way to know what profile I'm in without taking up 10 characters in the cmd line. This way, I save 9 chars.

I know this sounds like a bit of a ridiculous request (Who the heck needs emoji in terminal), but since the Mac terminal supports it, I suppose it wouldn't be a huge deal to get it working in IntelliJ?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161919

Comment: Hm. Any idea if it's easy to define a few emoji? I don't need the whole set. Just 3 of them.